# Using Contains as 'IN' cluase with LINQ in Entity Framework in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to return a list of items (vwProposedMigrations) where the DeptCode of the vwProposedMigrations is **IN** a list of depts that the user is authorised to manage.

*result* contains a list of departmentCode strings.  These have been loaded via an earlier entityQuery and are returned correctly.

```
var result = (from r in wtps.Schedule_Owner_DeptCode_Mappings select r.DeptCode).ToList();
var data = wtps.GetVwProposedMigrationsQuery().Where(x=>result.Contains(x.DepartmentCode));
LoadOperation dataLoad = wtps.Load<vwProposedMigration>(data);
dataLoad.Completed += new EventHandler(LoadvwProposedMigrationsOperation_Completed);
```

but receive this error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'
>   cannot be serialized as part of the query.
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' is not a supported
>   type.

I've tried using an `ObservableCollection` and a `string[]` to hold the list of department codes, but the same issue occurs.  I have seen lots of examples that use *Contains*, but these operate on the data once it has been loaded, as opposed to restricting the initial query.

I am trying to avoid loading the entire result set for vwProposedMigrations as it's about 38,000 rows, so my goal is to restrict the query to only those rows that are of interest to the user.

Thanks
Mick

Comment: What is the underlying database? (SQL? Oracle? etc.) and what is the type returned by `wtps.GetVwProposedMigrationsQuery()`?

Comment: The DB is MS-SQL. wtps is an instance of my Entity Framework DomainContext (WTPSDomainContext).  The return type is EntityQuery<vwProposedMigration>

Comment: try adding `.AsQueryable()` right before your `Where(..)`. It a long shot, but you could try :)

Comment: Intellisense isn't recognising AsQueryable as an option.

Comment: I just looked in the docomentation, [EntityQuery<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422815(v=vs.91).aspx) can never use Contains :(

Comment: hmm.  Bad times.  I'll have to come up with a dodgy workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

```
var data = wtps.GetVwProposedMIgrationsQuery().Where(x=>result.Any(z=>z.DepartmentCode == x.DepartmentCode))
```

Comment: I found this separately, but it is the method I eventually used.  Thanks for you answers

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
  var result = (from r in wtps.Schedule_Owner_DeptCode_Mappings select r.DeptCode);
  var data = wtps.GetVwProposedMigrationsQuery().Where(x=>result.Contains(x.DepartmentCode));
```